# holomorphic functions with special condition

Tags: rotations, holomorphic-functions, entire-functions

i want to find all holomorphic funtions $ f: \mathbb{C} \rightarrow \mathbb{C}$ with $ f(0)=0$  and $ f(f(f(f(z))))=z \forall z \in \mathbb C$

I would say rotations like $f(z)= |z| e^{i(arg z + \frac{\pi}{2})} $ can satisfy the conditions?
Am I right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Such a map is necessarily an automorphism of $\mathbb{C}$ and hence of the form $f(z) = az+b$. From here it is easy to see that only rotations qualify. So yes, you already found all of them.

EDIT: Seems like I slightly misread the question. Yes, rotations satisfy this as long as the angles add up to a multiple of $2\pi$.

Comment: How can i adapt my function then?

Comment: How do you conlude from $f(z)=az +b$ to rotations?

Comment: I do not understand your first comment. Why do you want to adapt it? As for your second comment, $b$ has to be $0$ because you demanded $f(0) = 0$. Hence $f(z) = az$ and $f(f(f(f(z)))) = a^4z$, i.e. $a \in \{1,i,-1,-i\}$. Therefore $f$ is a rotation. Your example is in fact $f(z) = iz$.

Comment: But I thought I have to rotate 90 degrees each, so 4 times? In your function $f(z)=iz$ you don*t consider that? I'm sure that I missed something:(

Comment: $f(z) = iz$ $is$ the rotation about 90 degrees.

Comment: I see:) So all my holomorphic functions are: $f(z)=az$ with $ a \in \{1,i,-1,i\}$?

Comment: Yes, this is correct.

Comment: Thank you Klaus:) It was very helpful.